# SQL distinct for two column

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a SQL table like below. This table is a bunch of sms messages between people. I want to get all the thread that exists. This basically means the last message between two people. How do i do this?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| sender_id  |  receiver_id  | message   | time         |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 123        |  456          | hi        | 4/17/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 123        |  111          | hi        | 4/18/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 123        |  555          | hi        | 4/19/2013    | 
-------------------------------------------------------- 
| 555        |  123          | hi        | 4/20/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 444        |  333          | hi        | 4/21/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 123        |  555          | hi        | 4/22/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 777        |  123          | hi        | 4/23/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get the response rows as below for **user= 123**. Notice how the sender_id and receiver_id as a whole are unique. Meaning a message that joe sent to bob is in the same thread as one that bob sent to joe.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| sender_id  |  receiver_id  | message   | time         |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 123        |  456          | hi        | 4/17/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 123        |  111          | hi        | 4/18/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 123        |  555          | hi        | 4/22/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 777        |  123          | hi        | 4/23/2013    | 
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: very dependent on the engine.

Comment: @codeNinja next time, put that in your tags - you'll get help quicker.

Comment: I've added the `mysql` tag for you. In the future, please add additional information with an [edit] to the question itself, in the body or tags (whichever is appropriate). It makes it easier to see, and it helps get the question to the people that can help you get an answer more quickly. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier to read version, which correctly handles date ordering (as shown in the question) and utilizes indexes:

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message, time FROM
(
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message, time
FROM myTable 
WHERE sender_id = 123 OR receiver_id = 123
ORDER BY time DESC
) a
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN sender_id = 123 THEN receiver_id
   ELSE sender_id END);
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5946c/9/0).

Comment: @ConradFrix To get the correct latest date, I think you do. I could be wrong about that, but your answer without the inline view does not produce the correct output.

Comment: I guess you did do need an inline view ;) nice catch

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message, time FROM your_table GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: Not quite. Messages from A to B and from B to A are the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, 
    IF(sender_id > receiver_id, CONCAT(sender_id, '_', receiver_id), 
   CONCAT(receiver_id, '_', sender_id)
    ) AS conversation_key, 
    message, `time` 
FROM sms_messages WHERE sender_id = 123
UNION ALL
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, 
    IF(
      sender_id > receiver_id, 
      CONCAT(sender_id, '_', receiver_id), 
  CONCAT(receiver_id, '_', sender_id)
    ) AS conversation_key, message, `time` 
FROM sms_messages WHERE receiver_id = 123
) t 
GROUP BY conversation_key ORDER BY NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't actually tested it, but the following query should return the newest<sup>1</sup> message for every distinct `sender_id`/`receiver_id` combination (in both "directions"):

```
SELECT *
FROM message m1
WHERE time = (
    SELECT MAX(time)
    FROM message m2
    WHERE
        (m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.receiver_id)
        OR (m1.sender_id = m2.receiver_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.sender_id)
)
```

In plain English: select every message such that it has maximal time of all the messages for the same sender/receiver or receiver/sender.

If desired, you can easily restrict that to a given user by amending the outer WHERE clause, for example:

```
--- || ---
AND (sender_id = 123 OR receiver_id = 123)
```

---

*<sup>1</sup> Note that there may be multiple "newest" messages if `time` is not unique.*

Answer (score 0):

the user 123 was only the example, I think the more general query is needed here.
This solution avoids time consuming joins, there is only assumption of maximum 10000 users (easily extendable)

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message, MAX(time), 
IF(sender_id<receiver_id, sender_id*10000+receiver_id, receiver_id*10000+sender_id) as thread_id 
FROM messages
GROUP BY thread_id
ORDER BY MAX(time) DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c65d3/30

UPDATE:
This version is free of number of users limitation:

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message, MAX(time), 
IF(sender_id<receiver_id, CONCAT(sender_id,receiver_id), CONCAT(receiver_id,sender_id)) as thread_id 
FROM messages
GROUP BY thread_id
ORDER BY MAX(time) DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c65d3/31